# Could win10 disable steam DOTA2 to prevent addiction for a long time such as two month

Tags: steam

Could win10 disable steam  DOTA2 to prevent addiction  for a long time such as two months ? how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

there is no option for that specifically in Windows 10, but you could get an external app to track your behaviour, e.g. for Android: "Quitzilla" or "No More! Quit your Addictions". You just have to remember to check in with your progress into the app